# How to opt-out usage data collection in Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)?

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) will collect usage information according to [this article](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-18-04-release-features/) and some others.

While there are claims you can opt-out in the installer, the installer of the beta2 version did not have such an option. 
After installation I do not see an obvious option in the (privacy) settings either.

And the articles sound like most of the data (like time needed by the installer, hardware information, etc.) will be sent right after installation.

I know how to remove `popcon`, but how is the other information collected and how can I opt out as soon as possible and prevent any data from be sent?

The mailinglist [thread](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2018-February/040139.html) do not contain any concrete information as well, so I wonder if it is already integrated. On the other hand should beta2 be the final beta before the release and the function should be included in the release according to the articles and the mailinglist.

Comment: Have you looked in System Settings > Privacy? And please read https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/ubuntu-data-collection-in-18-04-upgrades , then this comment http://disq.us/p/1qdmh2n for sanity. Keep calm and carry on.

Comment: I looked there and there was no option for it. The network related options for crash reports, location services and connection checks. Everything else there does not seem to be related to this or local only settings like trash bin and temp file cleanup.

Comment: And I am not talking about an upgrade, but a fresh installation I want to do. And I do NOT want to opt-in. popcon would be okay for me, but not sending details about my hardware and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is [`ubuntu-report`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-report), which currently sends a report once per Ubuntu version.
It supports an opt-out by using `ubuntu-report -f send no`, which will send a simple opt-out message allowing ubuntu to track the number of users even when they do not send hardware information.

More details about `ubuntu-report`, apport error reports and popularity-contest ("popcon") can be found here:
https://www.howtogeek.com/349844/how-to-stop-ubuntu-from-collecting-data-about-your-pc/

Comment: I edited the answer to add a few more details from the article, which seems to be a quite good answer. It will be interesting if the opt-out is recorded in some config file and if the config file can be used without even sending the opt-out message if you do not want to and possibly if you can uninstall the tool and force apt to ``hold`` it deinstalled.

Comment: I get this error message when I use the command given:

ERRO data were not delivered successfully to metrics server: couldn't send post http request: Post https://metrics.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/desktop/18.04:net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Answer (score 4):

I assume the question refers to "**Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) Beta 2**" currently available via:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/

e.g., "**ubuntu-18.04-beta2-desktop-amd64.iso**".

I downloaded this file, dated "**2018-04-04 05:29**", and did a full installation -- and at no point during the installation did I see the checkbox promised by Canonical to control sharing of hardware and installation information.

If the information is being involuntarily uploaded before the user has any means to prevent it, then this would be a violation of trust, and would reflect badly on the people who neglected to offer users a choice.

*After* installation and rebooting, the user has their first opportunity to access the "**Settings**" menu.

The "**Privacy**" section has "**Location Services**" defaulting to "*Off*", and "**Problem Reporting**" defaulting to "*Manual*", and "**Connectivity Checking**" defaulting to "*On*" (with a note saying, "*If your network communications are being monitored, it could be used to gather technical information about this computer.*").

Post-installation time seems too late to prevent uploading the hardware and installation experience information, but it's worth noting that an option to prevent such uploading is not present in the "**Settings**" menu (lest anyone speculate that the option to control this might be present there, and recommend to "keep calm and carry on").

Comment: I did the same and what worries me is that I cannot be certain where the option is or if it is integrated at all. The release will be at the end of april and it is announced that the function is integrated. I do not see any switches in the beta and cannot find information about things like program/package name and so on. The answer I am looking for is probably either "the package is called X and there is no switch (yet)" or "It is not part of the beta release and will/will not be in the final". But it seems hard to find anything concrete.

Answer (score 1):

I was confused by this also, but found https://www.howtogeek.com/349844/how-to-stop-ubuntu-from-collecting-data-about-your-pc/ which shows that it is in one of the dialog boxes you get on your first reboot.

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 opt-outs you can perform:

- Opt out of the `ubuntu-report` mechanism, by running `sudo ubuntu-report -f send no`.
- Opt out of the package popularity contest, by editing `/etc/popularity-contest.conf` and changing the value of `PARTICIPATE` to `no`.
- Opt out of automatic bug reports by visiting system settings (via the upper right corner menu), then *Privacy*, then *Problem Reporting*, and then unchecking *Automatic Problem Reporting*.